# EventEmitter - Why does the scope of this differ when adding a listener?

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I have a custom EventEmitter object, which emits when messages are received. After receiving a message, I'll publish it to a message exchange from an object, which will use a callback defined from that same object. Sample of the exchange function below:

```
function Exchange() {
    this.events = {
        published: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    };
}

Exchange.prototype.publish = function (data) {
    this.events.published(data);
};
```

On my receiving side, I have the custom EventEmitter which emits data:

```
server.on('data', function (data) {
    exchange.publish(data);
});
```

This works, but since `exchange.publish` and the listener uses the same arguments, I wanted to use:

```
server.on('data', exchange.publish);
```

This does not work, as the scope of `this` inside of the `publish` method changes, resulting in `this.events` to be undefined. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the function itself as the callback, so it's not called as method of the object and `this` won't refer to the object. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for more information about `this`.

You can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to explicitly bind the function to a certain object:

```
server.on('data', exchange.publish.bind(exchange));
```

Comment: That makes sense. I essentially use the publish function, but it's unaware where it came from. If I wrap it using `function (data) { exchange.publish..`, it also passes the object.